# How one shows a law is invariant/variant under a transformation in general case?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, invariants

Say we have a law of physics in a form of a differential equation:
$$
F(x,y,\dot{y},\dots) = 0.
$$
What is the general algorithm to show that this law is invariant under a certain transformation. The problem I am solving is electromagnetism laws under Galilean transf. but I want to learn the general mathematical approach to such problems.

Comment: Write an action that gives this law as its equations of motion. Find symmetries of the action.

Comment: thanks @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment about the action is good. At times it will be simpler to do the straightforward approach: to plug in all variables in terms of the new coordinates:

$$x = x(x', y', ..)$$
$$y=y(x', y', ...)$$
$$...$$
Then if the law is invariant (or "covariant") w.r.t. that transformation, after some simplification you should get the same law but just with every $x$ replaced with $x'$ etc. That can be easier depending on the case. Also I want to point out that the laws of electromagnetism are not invariant under a Galilean transformation. They are invariant under a Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Note also that with derivatives you'll need to use the chain rule rather than directly plugging in.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful.